# logging in through php

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I am trying to use my university account to login to a science database. I want to use my php codes to access the databases as well. The login page is:
 https://login.ezproxy.lib.rmit.edu.au/login and in order to log in, it needs username and password. 
In this page, the action in the login form redirect to "/login" directory that I cannot follow what to do. 
I used the following code to ask php to login:

```
    <?php
    $failed = "";
    $user = "myuser";
    $pass = "mypass";
    $url = "https://login.ezproxy.lib.rmit.edu.au/login";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    //set the POST parameters

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    
    if ($data != $failed)   //analyze the returned data
    {
        echo "Successfully logged in";
    } 
    else{
        echo "not logged in";
    }
    ?>
```

but this does not operate well. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: you never tell curl what your username is. you don't post ANY fields. all you're doing is a "naked" post with **NO** data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make these changes to your script

1. You need to tell the CURL what is your username and password.
2. Set the cookies for CURL

   ```
   //username and password of account
   $username = "";
   $password = "";

   //set the directory for the cookie using defined document root var
   $dir = DOC_ROOT."/ctemp";
   //build a unique path with every request to store 
   //the info per user with custom func. 
   $path ="";

   //login form action url
   $url="https://login.ezproxy.lib.rmit.edu.au/login"; 
   $postinfo = "user=".$username."&pass=".$password;

   $cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
   //set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
       "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
   curl_exec($ch);

   $html = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   print_r($html);
   ```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: *"Try this"* belongs in the comments section when something is "unclear". - Just as @JayBlanchard stated. Drop in code does nothing to instruct the OP as to what should be done and why.

Comment: Now go fix all of your answers where you told the OP to "try this" @FaizRasool

Comment: @JayBlanchard on my way to do that :)